# Unit testing onSuccess for a react query call

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-query

I have a component that looks like this:

```
<TestComponent refetch={fn} />
```

Within `TestComponent`, I have a save button that fires off a mutation:

```
    const handleSaveClick = () => {
        const reqBody: AddHotelRoomDescription = {...}

        addHotelRoomDescriptionMutation(reqBody, {
            onSuccess: () => {
                closeDrawer();
                handleRefetch();
            }
        })
    }
```

Within my test file for this component, I am trying to ensure `handleRefetch` gets called:

```
it('successfully submits and calls the onSuccess method', async () => {
        const mockId = '1234'

        nock(API_URL)
            .post(`/admin/${mockId}`)
            .reply(200);

        const user = userEvent.setup();
        const editorEl = screen.getByTestId('editor-input');

        await act( async () => { await user.type(editorEl, 'Updating description'); });
        expect(await screen.findByText(/Updating description/)).toBeInTheDocument();

        const saveButton = screen.getByText('SAVE');
        await act( async () => { await user.click(saveButton) });

        expect(mockedMutate).toBeCalledTimes(1);

        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(mockedHandleRefetch).toBeCalledTimes(1); <-- fails here
        })
    })
```

I am not sure how to proceed here. I know I can test useQuery calls by doing:

```
const { result } = renderHook(() => useAddHotelRoomDescription(), { wrapper }
```

But I think this is for a different situation.

Appreciate the guidance!

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would always be: "test it like the user". Users don't care if "the refetch function was called". What they care about is that the correct data is displayed on screen.

So, instead of testing the custom hook, test the component that *uses* the custom hook. Mount it, click on the button, and then wait and assert that the correct data shows up on the screen. If that data shows up because you called refetch in onSuccess, or because the query was invalidated, or because you called `queryClient.setQueryData` directly is an irrelevant implementation detail.